# Uploading csv to SQL table using R shiny

Tags: sql, r, database, dataframe, shiny

I've been scratching my head trying to figure this out.

So I've connected to the database but when I press the action button nothing is happening to the table.

The CSV is being converted to a data frame.

**UI**

```
library(shiny)
library(RJDBC)
library(dbtools)
library(jsonlite)
library(shinyjs)
library(DBI) 

# App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML(
          '#Uploadbutton{background-color:cyan}'
        ))
      ),

      actionButton("Uploadbutton","Upload"),
      p("Upload Members if data looks ok")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents")
    )

  )
)
```

**Server**

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    req(input$file1)

    data <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,header=TRUE)

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(data))
    }
    else {
      return(data)
    }
    data <- data.frame()
    data <<- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,header=TRUE)

    testdata <- read.csv("data",sep=",",row.names=1)

  observeEvent(input$Uploadbutton, {
       insert_into("data", "ANALYTICS.TEST_DATASTORE", con=lol, rows_per_statement=1)

        })

               }

  )
```

Comment: Is `insert_into()` a user-defined method of your own or from an R library?

Comment: It's a package called dbtools. The database is on db2, is there an alternative pacakage to use.

Comment: Think its an inhouse package that was modified (employee left the company) , what other package does the same job?

Comment: Please include `library` lines in actual post. See *edit* link. Then delete your above comment. What other packages? Look into the docs of the very libraries you use for insert procedures, but you will need to loop through dataframe rows! For DB2, RJDBC will be needed.

Comment: However, while I cannot determine `insert_into`, check the arguments. No where are you pulling in the dataframe object, *data* (unquoted). See how to define the source and destination table in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think what you are looking for is something like

```
DBI::dbWriteTable(con=lol, name = "ANALYTICS.TEST_DATASTORE",value = dta(),append = TRUE)
```

also I would structure the server function a bit different so that we don't need to use global variables

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  dta <- reactive({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    req(input$file1)

    data <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,header=TRUE)

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(data))
    }
    else {
      return(data)
    }

  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    dta()
  })

  observeEvent(input$Uploadbutton, {
    DBI::dbWriteTable(con=lol, name = "ANALYTICS.TEST_DATASTORE",value = dta(),append = TRUE)
  })
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This will upload the file for you.  Then, send the data to SQL Server.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),

      # Input: Select quotes ----
      radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                   choices = c(None = "",
                               "Double Quote" = '"',
                               "Single Quote" = "'"),
                   selected = '"'),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents")

    )

  )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    req(input$file1)

    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
             header = input$header,
             sep = input$sep,
             quote = input$quote)

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })

}
# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys figured out how to do it this was the server side.

> server <- function(input, output, session) {
>
> output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
>
> # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
>     # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
>    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.
>
> req(input$file1)
>
> data <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,header=TRUE)
>
> return(data)
>
> })
>
> observeEvent(input$Uploadbutton,
>
> {insert_into(read.csv(input$file1$datapath),"ANALYTICS.TEST_DATASTORE")},once=TRUE
>        )
>
> }